# Subversion: revision comment not visible with partial access to revision`s files

Tags: svn

**IDE:**

```
PHPStorm with Subversion plugin being a part of basic installation.
```

**Subversion users:**

```
UserFull has access to repository folders /a and /b
UserB has access to repository /b only
```

**Scenario:**

```
1. UserFull has committed changes (revision #123) with files
   /a/foo.js
   /b/bar.js
   with revision comment "Some changes XYZ"

2. UserB can see the revisions of the Repository (including the revision
   123). However, in the revision #123 he can only see /b/bar.js
   (which is technically correct with his permissions).
```

**Problem:**

```
UserB sees a <no comment> on #123.
And although he has a limited access to the files of the revision
(which is exactly what I was trying to set up),
I need him to be able to see the comment as well.
```

I am pretty sure there is a workaround but my lack of experience with Subverion becomes obvious. Any ideas on how to fine-tune the Subversion configuration to allow such revision comments to be visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I recall, this behavior is expected and is by design. If you don't have permissions to certain paths affected by the commit, you should not be able to view the log message.

Comment: Unfortunately, as there no options, your answer is to be treated as the only possible. Thank you.